# Ignoring certain child elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, removechild

I have the following code:

```
<table>
<th class="title2">The <i>very</i> hungry school</th><br />
<th class="title2">The very hungry school <span>yeah it works</span></th>
```

And..

```
    function capitalise(str) {
        if (!str) return;
        var counter = 0;
        var stopWords = ['a', 'an', 'and', 'at', 'but', 'by', 'far', 'from', 'if', 'into', 'of', 'off', 'on', 'or', 'so', 'the', 'to', 'up'];
        str = str.replace(/\b\S*[a-z]+\S*\b/ig, function(match) {
            counter++;
            return $.inArray(match, stopWords) == -1 || counter === 1 ? match.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1) : match;
        });
        return str;
    }


    $('th.title2').each(function() {    

        var capclone = $(this).clone().children(':not(i)').remove().end();

        capclone.text(capitalise(capclone.text()));

        capclone.append($(this).children(':not(i)'));

        $(this).replaceWith(capclone);

    });​
```

This code works for what I need it to do, but is there a way to maintain the italic element.  At the moment it gets removed, it's not a bad solution but it's not perfect.

Comment: Is it ok to append those child elements? If not, then It never worked for you. First and Second Instance are same.. Just that you happen to have the span tag at the end so it seems to you like you are ignoring them...

Comment: What I am trying to do is if it has italic elements it should not remove them.  Anything else is ok.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Ljn3s/ -> It is not removing it..  it is adding it to the end of the text because of capclone.append($(this).children());

Comment: Yes that is correct as this is how I need it 99% of the time.  I just need it to ignore any italic child elements.

Comment: This works for me SKS. http://jsfiddle.net/bizwizone/JGrPC/7/

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using `text()` use `html()` to get the html as it is the element and then upper case each word.  I simplified the regex slightly to `/\b\w+\b/ig` which will match a word boundary followed by one or more characters and a word boundary.  This will also match the initial character in a html tag, but it shouldn't cause any problems.  Instead of cloning and replacing the node I just update the html which should be faster as it's lighter on the DOM interaction.

```
function capitalise(str) {
    if (!str) return;
    var stopWords = ['a', 'an', 'and', 'at', 'but', 'by', 'far', 'from', 'if', 'into', 'of', 'off', 'on', 'or', 'so', 'the', 'to', 'up'];
    str = str.replace(/\b\w+\b/ig, function(match) {
        return $.inArray(match, stopWords) == -1 ? match.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1) : match;
    });
    return str;
}

$('th.title2').each(function() {
    var capclone = $(this), newHtml = capitalise(capclone.html());
    capclone.html(newHtml);
});​
```

You can play with the code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VTDve/1/).